# How to get pseudo-determinant of a square matrix with python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, naivebayes

I have a matrix which fails the singular test in which I am calculating for naive bayes classifier. I am handling the `ln(det(sigma))` portion of the equation.

```
if np.linalg.cond(covarianceMatrix) < 1/sys.float_info.epsilon:
    return np.log(np.linalg.det(covarianceMatrix))
else:
    return a pseudo determinant
```

When the covariance matrix is singular, I must find the pseudo determinant. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

1. First compute the eigenvalues of your matrix

```
    eig_values = np.linalg.eig(covarianceMatrix)
```

2. Then compute the product of the non-zero eigenvalues (this equals the pseudo-determinant value of the matrix),

```
    pseudo_determinent = np.product(eig_values[eig_values > 1e-12])
```

Comment: I am trying to implement this solution but I faced the error: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'float'. Can I ask if you know how to solve it? it looks like I need to loop through the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use numpy's pinv to calculate the pseudo inverse and then use that to calculate the determinant?
http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/inverse/inverse.html

Answer (score 0):

The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901908/13284610) would give an error (> sign not supported between tuple and float) as the `np.linalg.eig` function gives both eigen values and eigen vectors in a tuple. Select the first element of the tuple to get eigen values and then compute the pseudo determinant.

```
eig_values = np.linalg.eig(covarianceMatrix)[0]
pseudo_determinent = np.product(eig_values[eig_values > 1e-12])
```